# Using CSS Level 4 max function in SASS for iPhone X safe-area Styling

Tags: css, sass

I want to use the CSS Level 4 function 'max' in SASS for safe-area styling like documented [here](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/).
But this function conflicts with the SASS max function. Is there a way to use the CSS Level 4 max function in SASS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your want to use the CSS Level 4 max function in SASS you have to quote, and unquote the max function.

```
@supports(padding: unquote('max(0px)')) {
  padding-left: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-left))');
  padding-right: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-right))');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the accepted answer should be corrected to

```
@supports(padding: unquote('max(0px)')) {
  padding-left: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-left))');
  padding-right: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-right))');
}
```

Otherwise `max(0px)` would get evaluated by SASS to 0px, which is supported everywhere and the rules will be applied to all browsers, even those not supporting CSS max().