# Using env(safe-area-inset-top) in SCSS with max() function

Tags: css, sass, webkit, iphone-x

I am developing a site which I wish to display correctly on devices with a notch (particularly the iPhone X as I own one).
In [this page](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/) the following code sample is given:

```
@supports(padding: max(0px)) {
    .post {
        padding-left: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-left));
        padding-right: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-right));
    }
}
```

However when I have this set, in Chrome I can see that it's not valid (see photo linked below)

[image: PHOTO LINK]

Is there a way to correct this or can an SCSS `@if` statement be used to detect if a parent element has padding > 0 and if not add `1rem` of padding to it?

My problem is not the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439446/using-css-level-4-max-function-in-sass-for-iphone-x-safe-area-styling/47439447#47439447), this is how I am using the code, I have also tried putting this in a standard CSS file without the `unquote` however its not working either.

Comment: Check out the browser support for the `env` CSS function. It seems that Chrome doesn't support this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env

Comment: Also SCSS can't be used to detect dimensions of HTML elements. SCSS is just a more comfortable syntax for CSS which may be used for developing CSS. The browser itself will never see the SCSS code since SCSS is transpiled to CSS which the browser will then use for rendering.

Comment: Thank you @Teemoh, do you know of any ways to have a cross-browser solution for this?

Comment: Also, in firefox it is still an "invalid property value"

Comment: In Firefox CSS `max` is not supported. There won't be a cross-browser solution for this. The article you referenced also explains that only Safari implemented the necessary features. I think you should just add some kind of fallback with a default padding of e.g. 12px for all unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 14):

If I read your question right you are referring to the [css max function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) not the max function provided by Sass - also the example is CSS and hence needs the mentioned Sass 'hack' to work in SCSS.

The first thing you need to deal with is the iOS 11.0 - 11.2 implementation using `constant`. The easiest way to do this is to assign the safe-area-inset to CSS variables.

In the example below I've created a default value of 0px for all variables – but you could also use fallback values when using the variables `var(--some-var, 12px)` (uses 12px if --some-var is not defined).

The second part is your code using the --safe-area-inset variables.

I hope it makes sense :-)

```
:root {
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        Assign the default/constant/env values to CSS variables
    */
    --safe-area-inset-top   : 0px;
    --safe-area-inset-right : 0px;
    --safe-area-inset-bottom: 0px;
    --safe-area-inset-left  : 0px;  

    /* it is probably safe to skip the `constant` test in 2023 :) */
    @supports (top: constant(safe-area-inset-top)){
        --safe-area-inset-top   : constant(safe-area-inset-top);
        --safe-area-inset-right : constant(safe-area-inset-right);
        --safe-area-inset-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
        --safe-area-inset-left  : constant(safe-area-inset-left);          
    }

    @supports (top: env(safe-area-inset-top)){
        --safe-area-inset-top   : env(safe-area-inset-top);
        --safe-area-inset-right : env(safe-area-inset-right);
        --safe-area-inset-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
        --safe-area-inset-left  : env(safe-area-inset-left);            
    }          
}


@supports(padding: Max(0px)) {
    .post {
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------   
           Use the CSS variables in the max function   
        */
        padding-left:  Max(12px, var(--safe-area-inset-left));
        padding-right: Max(12px, var(--safe-area-inset-right));
    }
}
```

Comment: In some SASS libs using CSS `max` function will throw an error:
`... is not a number for 'max'`

Couple of quick fixes available, either `m#{a}x(#{$numbers})` or redefining SASS' min/max fns: 
```sass
@function max($numbers...)
  @return m#{a}x(#{$numbers})

@function min($numbers...)
  @return m#{i}n(#{$numbers})
  
``` 
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2378#issuecomment-433868712

Comment: You are correct - I've updated the example to use uppercase Max to bypass the lowercased Sass max function.

Comment: That's a neat way to overcome the issue!

Answer (score 13):

You need to unquote max in @supports too, the referenced example should be:

```
@supports(padding: unquote('max(0px)')) {
  padding-left: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-left))');
  padding-right: unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-right))');
}
```

Comment: I've updated the example with an upper-case bypass - unquote is not necessary.